# SQL Server column divide with column with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted my outcome to be something like below, the initial null value in either hit1 or hit0n1 become 0, and when hit1 divide by 0 then the percentage will become 0%.

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(10),ISNULL(a6.hit1*100,0)/NULLIF(a7.hit0n1, 0))+ '%'
.........
 left join
(select category,hit,COUNT(hit) as hit1 from(Select Category,UpdateTime,due,
 Case When UpdateTime < Due Then 1 Else 0 End As hit From FeedbackDetail Where StatusName ='Closed'  and FeedbackDatetime>=DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE())) a where hit = 1
 Group by category, hit) a6 On a1.Category = a6.Category 

 left join
 (select category,COUNT(hit) as hit0n1 from ( Select  Category,UpdateTime,due,
 Case when UpdateTime < Due then 1 else 0 end as hit From FeedbackDetail Where StatusName ='Closed'  and FeedbackDatetime>=DATEADD(day,-31, GETDATE()) ) a 
 Group by category)
 a7 on a1.Category = a7.Category
```

Expected Outcome

```
 hit1  hit0n1   percentage
  _____ _______ ____________
   5       0        0%
    0       0        0%
   3       10      33.3%
```

but my code display this instead :

```
hit1  hit0n1   percentage
_____ _______ ____________
 5      null      NULL
 6       6       100%
 3       10      33.3%
```

there is null value in hit0n1, i want to elimate the null value and at the same time i want to avoid 0 number.

Comment: i have edited the queston.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  hit1       = a6.hit1,
        hit0n1     = isnull(a7.hit0n1, a6.hit1),
        percentage = CONVERT(varchar(10),
                             ISNULL(a6.hit1 * 100.0,0) / ISNULL(a7.hit0n1, a6.hit1) ) + '%'
```

if you wanted the result in 3 decimal places,

use `convert()` to convert the calculation result to `decimal(10,3)` before convert to `varchar(10)`

```
percentage = CONVERT(varchar(10),
                     CONVERT(decimal(10,3),
                             ISNULL(a6.hit1 * 100.0,0) / ISNULL(a7.hit0n1, a6.hit1) ) 
                            ) + '%'
```

EDIT : change to handle hit0n1 = 0

```
select  
    hit1, 
    hit0n1  = isnull(hit0n1, hit1),
    percentage = CONVERT(varchar(10),
                     CONVERT(decimal(10,3),
                             ISNULL(ISNULL(hit1 * 100.0, 0) / NULLIF(ISNULL(hit0n1, hit1), 0), 0) ) 
                            ) + '%'
```

EDIT : explanation on the percentage calculation

`ISNULL(hit0n1, hit1)` returns first non null value. If hit0n1 is null then it will return hit1 value

if `hit0n1` is 0, that division will be error cause it is divide by 0. To handle it `NULLIF( <expression> , 0)` is use to return NULL value if `<expression>` is 0. And the result of the division will be NULL value

the final `ISNULL()` is to change the NULL value to 0

Comment: both values hit1 and hit0n1 got from count, integer but there are null value in it.

Comment: you mean hit1 may also be 0 ?

Comment: can you update your question with such example ? and show how would you like the result to looks like

Comment: sorry for mislooking something, you save my day! by the way, can you explain this line to me 'ISNULL(ISNULL(hit1 * 100.0, 0) / NULLIF(ISNULL(hit0n1, hit1), 0), 0) )' as i am not really understand on this.

Comment: @kit. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

In place of NULL what do you want to replace then?
If you want to use the same value as first column then may be you can go with `ISNULL(hit0n1,hit1)`

`NULLIF` returns `NULL` if both expressions are equal otherwise it returns expression one which is also a `NULL` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to filter something, you can use `WHERE` or `HAVING`. As `HAVING` requires aggregation, I think it will be clearer to use `WHERE`. As, we do not want to have `NULL` values in the result, we can use:

```
WHERE a6.hit1 IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(a7.hit0n1, 0) IS NOT NULL
```

We check for `0` only the `a7.hit0n1` as `0 divided on something` is valid statement.

Also, if you are working with huge amount of data, you can add [filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) indexes on your tables, excluding the `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
Select hit1,
case when isnull(hit0n1,hit1)!=0 then isnull(hit0n1,hit1) end as [hit0n1],
cast(round((hit1/(case when isnull(hit0n1,hit1)!=0 then isnull(hit0n1,hit1) end)*100),2) as varchar(100))+'%' 
from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
```

SQL Server 2014